# How to determine whether a process is actively using internet

Tags: internet, process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I capture network traffic of a single process?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11709/how-can-i-capture-network-traffic-of-a-single-process)

I want to write a script which start/resume downloading big file using a download manager say wget only if the browser [say firefox] is not loading anything [actively not using internet].

How can i check from a script whether a process actively using internet or not ?

`ss -p` will give the connected process but can't say wheter they are active or not

**[nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/)** is a visual solution but i can't use it in script due to its dynamic nature