# offline libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice, offline

Problem: when my laptop is offline, libreoffice freezes. When network is on, everything seems normal, when I shut down the network, libreoffice hangs.

This is the case on my laptop, I struggled with for some time, even purged and reinstalled the whole package, but still the same.  I then pulled the ethernet plug in my desktop PC and got the same result.

Both PC-s are ubuntu 14.04 64bit.  Libreoffice version is 4.2.8.2. build:2.

EDIT: I just tested a second laptop (same config).  Exactly same result: disable network and LO hangs.

I hope for help on this, need to be able to run libreoffice offline!

Edit2 (request from Pilot6):

```
bf@bf-Dell:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G84GL [Quadro FX 1700] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 049a
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
bf@bf-Dell:~$
```

- but remember: 3 different PC's

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: This is something that bothers me for some time now... what does LO try to do online when just working on a document ?

Comment: This question might be helpful to track down the problem : https://askubuntu.com/questions/11709/how-can-i-capture-network-traffic-of-a-single-process

Comment: start it from command line and when it stalls see if there is a message in the terminal

Comment: alci: I checked that site, but far to complicated for me.  Rinzwind: I already did that.  No output in the terminal

Comment: @amalgamas could you run this command from the terminal: strace -olo_network.txt -f -e trace=network -s 10000 libreoffice This should result in a text file named lo_network.txt with all system calls regarding the network that LO makes. Not sure I will be able to find a solution out of it, but it certainly will help...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Turns out i had recently worked on a document on a shared drive over the local network. That document was still listed in my recently edited docs in the File Menu.

I cleared them and removed the menu entry entirely. That seems to have helped at least with localc. Have not tried the others though.